# How can I configure my logback system so that it could create a log file as soon as a time based rolling cycle complete?

Tags: spring, file, groovy, java-8, logback

My application is based on Jdk8, groovy 2.4 as language and on the top of Spring Framework. As a logger I'm using 'logback' dependencies. (*group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.1.8'*). Basically, RollingFileAppender is working fine for me, But currently, I have some additional requirement.

For an example,
Suppose the specific logger function is invoked at **2018-05-16 11:08:50**, A record entered into error.log and no rolling file is created. Well, when the next execution occurs approximately after 6 minutes at **2018-05-16 11:15:05**, A fresh file is created **error.2018-05-16-11-08.log** and **error.log** file is refreshed with only the new message. This behavior is as per the documentation. But currently, I'm in need of instant creation of log file as soon as the rolling complete. In that case, the new file **error.2018-05-16-11-08.log** which is created actually at **2018-05-16 11:15:05**, I need to create the same file actually at **2018-05-16 11:09:00** (means as soon as the minute based rolling is complete).

```
<appender name="ERROR_LOG"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>logs/error.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>logs/error_log/error.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm}.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}\t%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
```

I know there is a way, simply eliminating input  property. If I omit that property, The problem partially gets resolved for me. But, in that case, error.log will not be created which have to be retained.

Please, feel free to ask me anything regurding this issue.

Comment: you have mentioned rolling policy as TimeBasedRollingPolicy, which creates new log file based on specific time. go with either FixedWindowRollingPolicy or SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy that might meet your requirement.

Comment: Basically, I need to maintain TimeBasedRollingPolicy as per early requirement. It will be ok if it can even be solved programmatically.